# unknown if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, filtering

What does `if(td)` condition do here? This code is written to search a row in a table.
`var input` is the search box, `var table` is the table.

```
function myFunction() {
    // this function filters the table using search box
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;

    input = document.getElementById("myInput"); // the search box
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // the table
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");      // the row of table

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {  // why do we need this condition here?
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: If a row has no `<td>` elements then the variable will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

The code `if (td)` checks to make sure there is something in the td and it is real so that your next line wont throw an error when it looks for the `td.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

`td` contains the data for the row and you are matching the data with some filter. Now what if `td` doesn't exists, you will get an error of `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

The result is a live HTMLCollection of found elements in the order they appear in the sub-tree. If no elements were found, (in your case if there is a `<tr>` without a single `<td>` inside) the HTMLCollection is empty.

If now you get an empty HTMLCollection then the innerHTML method you are calling to your next row will result to the following error and your code will break.

> "TypeError: td is undefined"